# Pulling data from fixture error : Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js, cypress, build-automation

When I tried to pull data from fictures into my test case I got an Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
error message.

Code:
describe('My First Test', () => {

```
beforeEach(function() {
    cy.fixture("DataFile").then((data) => {
      this.key = data
      
    })
  })

it('Does not do much!', () => {
    cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
    cy.get("form input[name='name']").type(this.key.Name)
    cy.get("form input[name='email']").type(this.key.Email)
   cy.get("#exampleInputPassword1").type(this.login.key.Password)
   cy.get('select').select(this.key.Gender)

})
```

Error:
Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access properties of `this`, use a function instead of an arrow function

```js
it('Does not do much!', function() {              // function here gets correct 'this'
  cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
  cy.get("form input[name='name']").type(this.key.Name)
  cy.get("form input[name='email']").type(this.key.Email)
  cy.get("#exampleInputPassword1").type(this.login.key.Password)
  cy.get('select').select(this.key.Gender)
})
```

or you can move the fixture closer to the tests (less optimal but overall not by much)

```js
it('Does not do much!', () => {
  cy.fixture("DataFile").then((data) => {
    cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
    cy.get("form input[name='name']").type(data.key.Name)
    cy.get("form input[name='email']").type(data.key.Email)
    cy.get("#exampleInputPassword1").type(data.login.key.Password)
    cy.get('select').select(data.key.Gender)
  })     
})
```